# Custom dialog box in wpf issue

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, modal-dialog

I'm calling my custom dialog window with this code:

```
GUI.SLDialog sd = new GUI.SLDialog();
if (sd.ShowDialog() == false)
{
    return;
}
```

But sd.ShowDialog() always returns nothing (i think), because the function breaks, but the waypoint at `return;` isn't reached.

Dialog is automaticly closing when I add to button:

```
this.DialogResult = false;//or true
```

Anybody know what am I doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance for your help.
C.H.

@edit
This is my SLDialog:
xaml: http://wklej.org/hash/9fb67fb0c7c/
cs: http://wklej.org/hash/16e3ccc6c0d/

Comment: I'm assuming `DialogResult` is a `bool` and not a `System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult`...

Comment: Yup. I'm using wpf only everywhere.

Comment: Can you show some code of `SLDialog`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I can tell you much here unless you post the code for the dialog but I do have a suggestion in the mean time.

Since you're already unhappy with the standard dialog boxes and customization is clearly an option why not move towards what people are coming to expect? Instead of your standard dialog why not just create a user control that lays over the rest of your UI and blurs everything out from the background? Much like a jquery dialog box you might see on a web page.

Modality is easier to control since it's just a matter of covering your entire app window with a translucent rectangle and then make the dialog window appear however you want.

Just a suggestion.

Comment: Doing this would additionally require to somehow control modality with respect to code execution. Usually when you `Window.ShowDialog()`, the execution of the code right after that is suspended until you close the window.